# Sharing of information between back end and front end developers

Tags: web, postman, conventions, methodology

This question is not related to code or any bug. I have an organisation related query. I am a front end developer. I consume web API's developed by the back end developers in my company. The problem here is, they share it via postman. API's are segregated project wise in folders. Problem is, the nomenclature of the API as well as the functionality differs. This creates lot of confusion for me while consuming API's. secondly, There is no indication that whether the API is deployed on a server or not. So sometimes, I end up writing the code and realize that the specific API is not deployed yet.

My question is, how does the world do it? How is the communication between developers established with this specific domain? How can one overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope i interpret your question correctly:

One of the methods used in the industry is scrum (specifically daily stand ups) where you talk about the work you intend to perform that day. This will give the back-end guys an opportunity to tell you its not yet ready. It really depends on the culture in the company. Why are they writing endpoints not yet deployed, and if not deployed, how difficult is it for you to make them deploy them?

Another way is DevOps which many think of as scrum for the entire value chain.

These methologies are however not something you can dictate, but they arose because of the problem you are refering to.

In practice: You should probably ask to get another folder called "SafeToUse" or "ReadyForConsumption" in Postman and in this way you can clearly see whats on its way and whats ready.

I hope this answers your question. I can't recommend anything more specific not knowing the kind of work you perform - normally in my experience the front- and backend for a given project is developed with close communication.